# Ajax load different wordpress content based on user click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to load different templates through $.ajax based on what buttons a user clicks. I know how to do it with one template file, but can't seem to find a way to adjust the code to load different template based on click (without repeating the code).

Here's the relevant part of the ajax call:

```
var $this = $('#my-data');

$('#button-foo').click(function() {

    $.ajax({

        url: myAjax.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'my_ajax_action'
        },
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $this.empty();
            $this.addClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function(){
            $this.removeClass('loading');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $this.append(data);
        },
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

And here's my Wordpress function:

```
function my_ajax_action() {

            include(locate_template( 'part-template-foo.php' ));
            die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action');
```

Now what I need would be to include 4 different templates (part-template-bar.php, part-template-foobar.php, etc) based on user click. Something like:

```
function my_ajax_action() {

        if ($_REQUEST['template'] == 'foo') {
            include(locate_template( 'part-foo.php' ));
            die();
        }

        if ($_REQUEST['template'] == 'bar') {

            include(locate_template( 'part-bar.php' ));
            die();
        }

        ...

    }
```

Any hint on how could I do this without having to repeat the js code and wp function four times? Thank you.

Comment: u can add data(after action: 'my_ajax_action')...and in back end verify that field with if else condition

Comment: I tried to add ( action:  "my_ajax_action", template: $template) and make the var $template change on user click if that's what you mean. Couldn't make it work though. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: try to use get_template_directory instead of include(locate_template(...))

Comment: Thanks but that's not the point. I need a way to create an if else condition in the php based on what user clicks.

Comment: im not going to do this for you because it is simple. Apply a class to your buttons and use that as the click identifer, then apply a unique id or data attribute, get this and pass as a variable in your ajax function.

Comment: I'm kinda new to jquery/ajax hence it's not simple to me, It's the second day I spend on this. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: You were right, it was much easier then I thought, I was able to achieve the result I wanted by following your advice, thank you. Something like:


  `$(this).each(function() {
   
   var uniqueData = $(this).attr('id');
   $(this).attr('data-type',uniqueData);
   
  });
  
  var $template = $(this).attr('data-type');`